# Show that if the sequence converges the limits are equal?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

If $\{{a_n}\}$  is convergent

Show that

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}  \{a_{n+1}\} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \{a_n\}$

I cannot find a start as I know only that when a series is convergent but I dont know how to tackle up this problem as far as I have understood is a very rough sketch that involves using functions as supposing a function $f(x) = \{a_n\}$ and then if we add +1 $f(x+1) = \{a_{n+1}\}$ then it will not effect the limits as constants are ignored witht the limits. I am very confused here just started the sequences and cant understand this particular problem starting point so I will be glad for you to help and please correct my concepts about limits as well as you can see they are pretty messed up

Comment: In latex, you group things (for example to put them as exponent) with {things}.

Comment: As for your question, just write down the definition of the limit.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

$$|a_n-\ell|<\epsilon\;\forall n\ge N\Rightarrow |a_{n+1}-\ell|<\epsilon\;\forall n\ge N-1 $$

Answer (score 0):

From triangle inequality we know that
$$|a_{n+1}-a|\leq |a_{n+1}-a_n|+|a_n-a|.$$
Also $(a_n)$ is convergent so is cauchy. Then $\forall\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that for all $n>n_1$ and $ n>n_2$ we have $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\varepsilon$ and $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$, respectively. So there exists $n_3=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$ such that 
$$|a_{n+1}-a|\leq |a_{n+1}-a_n|+|a_n-a|<2\varepsilon$$ which completes the proof.